# Question about tutorial: "spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases", could there be an easier way?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, persistence

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

According to this link you need to set up configuration class etc. To me it seems like a lot of work, for something that we could only annotate specific @Entity. Is this possible? What am I missing?

So my wishful thinking would be:

pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MSSQL Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mssql-jdbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=test;encrypt=false
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

And the entity (e.g. TestEntity.java):

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "[test]")
@Entity(connection = "mssql|h2")   //so here you could maybe define it?
@ToString
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: Your question seems like more of a recommendation.  I don't think this suggestion will be adopted, though, because the Entity does not need and should not have any knowledge of the connection.

Comment: JPA is built around one data store. While some providers (EclipseLink for one https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/toplink/solutions/usingmultipledbs.htm ) have mechanisms to have entities with relationships to other entities and handle them across datastores within one logical context, it isn't straightforward or a simple feat, and would certainly be error prone to have to define the behavior across all other well defined features within JPA.

Comment: @Chris
There is way to have multiple data stores. With the configuration .class. Why would we not simplify it?

Comment: @lane.maxwell it does not need too much knowledge about the connection.. just so that repository will know which database to look in. 

It was just an idea. Since entity has a (annotation)-Table defined. It would be interesting to also let it know which database connection should it use to access that (annotation)-Table

Comment: I'm not saying it is a bad idea - only it needs more than you realize to make a reality. Behind the scenes, you have to define the persistence unit these entities go in, and how they handles any relationships between entities in different databases. What does inheritance or mappedSuperclass or fetch joins mean in such conditions? Take a look at the existing solution I mentioned, and even the been configuration one and you'll see why it wouldn't immediately go in to JPA. You can do this yourself with your own annotation reader and a composite Persistence unit